# Как правильно построить отношение Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

Упрощенная структура (основные поля для понимания):

```
AppUsers
 -id
 -nik_name

Bans
-id
-nik_name

Notes
-id
-nik_name
```

Строю так:

```
class AppUser extends Model
{

public function ban()
{
    return $this->hasOne('App\Ban','nik_name','nik_name');
}

public function note(){
    return $this->hasOne('App\Note','nik_name','nik_name');
}
}
```

Не могу понять как в контроллере вызвать сразу обе связи. По одной получается:

```
 $userApp = AppUser::with('ban')->find($id);
```

А как сразу обе сразу связать - не понимаю.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Я бы рекомендовал делать связи по id пользователя. Если же вы конечно, точно уверенны что поле `nik_name` уникально и есть соответствующая проверка.

Например добавьте поле в таблицу Bans - 'appUsers_id' чтобы не явно связать данную таблицу с таблицей Bans.

Вот примеры для связей:

```
AppUsers
-id
-nik_name

Bans
-id
-appUsers_id
-nik_name

Notes
-id
 -appUsers_id
-nik_name
```

Отношение тут же будет еще проще:

```
public function ban()
{
    return $this->hasOne(Ban::class);
}

public function note(){
    return $this->hasOne(Note::class);
}
```

Для связи пробуйте вызвать запрос с хелпером with:

```
$query = AppUsers::with('ban', 'note')->get();
```

Comment: Уникально, проверки есть. Я не могу понять как одним запросом в контроллере получить обе связи

Comment: Более подробно про активную загрузку нескольких отношений, можно прочитать в документации https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading